# Any way to merge function calls to one call in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

```
def clock():
    for action in self.actions:
        action()
```

The code shows a `clock` update function which will call all actions registered before to drive the system module.

Problems is function call is expensive in the implementation of `cpython`, and the clock will be called at a very high frequency, the profile result shows that the local time of clock is like `3-5%` of total. so I was wondering that would it be possible to merge all the actions into one big function **at runtime**.

If the actions will not change at runtime, I can use `AST` module to merge the code into one at import time or publish time. But I don't figure out any way to do this at runtime.

Comment: 3-5% of the total program time is in this function?  That isn't very much.  If you cut it in half you'll save only 2% of total program time.  Hardly worth messing with the AST!  Better might be to implement the hot loop as a C extension (or use Numba).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I suppose most of the time consumption is at the function call instead of the `for` loop, So simply using `capi` to do the `for` loop and function call to python will only remove the interpretation time of the bytecode, now it's compiled, which I don't think will be better than 2%. And the `action` is concrete business logic for which using c is not an option.

Comment: What sort of business logic is it?  If it's mathematical in nature, use Numba.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Actually the cpython implementation is embedded in the engine system, so `JIT` is also not an option, `cython` may work in some level, but compiling will lose many dynamic features. BTW: it'a part of game engine and many c library is wrapped using `c-api`.